# Good tools for building a call for proposals in Civi?

Tags: custom-fields

I want to do a call for proposals for a conference. I can just use a profile and custom fields for people to enter the info, but I'd prefer for them to be able to save it in progress before eventually submitting, and also to track whether or not it had been approved.

I know there are other specialized tools for this, but I was hoping maybe there was a way to do it in Civi so I don't have to set one up. We're running Civi in Drupal.

Comment: what CMS are you using. answers may well be dependent on that, eg for Drupal it might be easier to do the required via Webform-CiviCRM

Comment: Zak, it would help to know the version of CiviCRM that you are running (as well as the version of Drupal).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zak,  I agree with Peter's comment. If you are using Drupal, you can use the CiviCRM Drupal webforms integrations.  **There were a few good examples of these at the CiviCRM User summit** last week  (i.e - Susan's ReThink Church example - which is essentially what you want).

Basic concept: User logs in and starts to fill out a multi page webform that saves the data on their CiviCRM record.  If you want to add a little custom code, you can have the final page be a "signature page" so that it can not be edited again.